# Why does route globbing fail for my url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble globbing a url in my `routes.rb` as defined in the rails guide.

```
get 'photos/*other', to: 'photos#unknown'
```

I have this line of code in my `routes.rb` file:

```
 constraints(Codeopenhub) do
   get '/', to: 'codeopenhub#index'
 end
```

As of right now this code will catch the url `code.openhub.net` but I need to catch urls that look like this `code.openhub.net/other_stuff`. Here is what I've tried:

```
 constraints(Codeopenhub) do
   get '/*', to: 'codeopenhub#index'
 end
```

This doesn't work..... It will throw a 404. I then tried this:

```
constraints(Codeopenhub) do
   match '/*', to: 'codeopenhub#index', via: [:get]
 end
```

This didn't work either. I have a `lib/constraints/codeopenhub.rb` file that contains this code:

```
class Codeopenhub
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.include?(ENV['CODE_SUBDOMAIN'])
  end
end
```

Basically this is saying that if the url has the subdomain `code` then it should go to `codeopenhub#index`. I'm confused as to why my routes are not matching. Why won't a url thats `code.openhub.net/foo` not match with the `*`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, according to the guide, that you need to have a name attached to the star, since the value that gets matched is put into the params.  Try this route:

```
get '*foo', to: 'codeopenhub#index'
```

You would then route `code.openhub.net/taco` to `codeopenhub#index` with the value `params[:foo] = 'taco'`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an optional parameter. Whenever I need it I put the param name inside parentheses, so I would write it like this:

```
 constraints(Codeopenhub) do
   get '/(:other)', to: 'codeopenhub#index'
 end
```

See more information in the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters